# MongoDB c# driver SetOnInsert misunderstood

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I wonder how to only insert a new Guid when the object was created and not updated.

I thought therefore using the SetOnInsert is the right way - but it doesn't work!

Every time I run the code below the object is getting a new `_id`:

```
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode = GuidRepresentationMode.V3;
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer<Guid>(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));

FilterDefinition<TestClass> filter = """{ Path: "a.b.c.d" }""";
var builder = Builders<TestClass>.Update;
var update = builder.SetOnInsert("_id", Guid.NewGuid()).Set("Path", "a.b.c.d").Set("Name", "c.d");
FindOneAndUpdateOptions<TestClass> options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<TestClass> { IsUpsert = true, ReturnDocument = MongoDB.Driver.ReturnDocument.After };

var read = collNamespace.FindOneAndUpdate<TestClass>(filter, update, options);
```

How can I use `FindOneAndUpdate` or some other method to only set the `_id` once?

Comment: Why are you using `FindOneAndUpdate`rather than `UpdateOne`? If you're not using the before document (you're not even assigning it to a variable) then there's no reason to use it and it's just creating unnecessary work for the database.

Comment: Also, if it's setting a new id regardless, you should submit a bug report to the Mongo C# driver repository on GitHub.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Oh, it's just an example to post here. I modified the code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had to sleep. On the [first run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugJRo.png) it's set, and on the [second run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8LQr.png) it's unchanged when using the code as you have it. I'm testing against MongoDB 5.0.16 Community using the 2.19.0 version of the .NET driver. Can you provide more precise steps on how to reproduce?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Oh - I forgot to write that I use another Guid Representation. I modified my post.